# How do we distinguish "line" from "verse" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, semantics

"Versus" in latin can be a line of a writing and in poetry is a verse.
Any example:I'm writing these lines because I want you to see the verses I wrote.
Can I just say:"Scribo hos versus quia volo te videre eos."?

Comment: What do you mean by "line"?

Comment: I was thinking in Portuguese. Maybe in English the word doesn't work as the same way. When we write something, we write it in lines(the lines on the paper) a letter or anything. The latin word Linea doesn't have the meaning of something you wrote, it's more like a mark. So when I say that I write lines whose verses I want someone to see, I wonder how can I use these two words in latin since they are translated only as "versus"

Comment: Since the Romans didn't have line paper, they don't have a word specifically for that. I think perhaps you might want something like *sententiae* or *scriptiones* or even just *scripta*. But there's something for localization that's just missing here.

Comment: I think I can use "litteras" in that case. We use words in lines. I recall Cicero saying "pauca ad tuas litteras rescribam"

Comment: Yes, *litterae* would be fine, too.